# __weak HAL_GPIO_EXT1_Callback ( uint16_t GPIO_Pin) even though I have defined HAL_GPIO_EXT1_Callback ( uint16_t GPIO_Pin) in my source

Tags: hal, bluepill, stm32cubeide

I'm working in STM32 CubeIDE with a Blue Pill board.

To control the size of main.c I have gathered groups of functions together in to several c/h pair files.  One of the pairs is 'myirqcallbacks.c/h".  At the moment I have two UART IRQs and an external pin IRQ callback in this c/h pair.

The UARTs work fine but the EXT IRQ fails to call my code.  It runs the __weak copy in stm32f1xx_hal_gpio.c instead.

When the code was in main.c it ran OK.

It seems that the compiler can't see my EXT IRQ callback function so fails to deprecate the __weak copy of the callback.  It can however see the two UART callback functions in there.  Is there some difference in the structure of the GPIO and UART IRQs?

myirqcallbacks.h

```
    /*
 * myirqcallbacks.h
 *
 *  Created on: 13 May 2020
 *      Author: Paul
 */



#ifndef SRC_MYIRQCALLBACKS_H_
#define SRC_MYIRQCALLBACKS_H_

void HAL_GPIO_EXT1_Callback ( uint16_t GPIO_Pin);  // SIM Reset detected

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);  // Outgoing debug, control and up-the-line data.

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) ; // Data from SIM


#endif /* SRC_MYIRQCALLBACKS_H_ */
```

myirqcallbacks.c

```
     * myirqcallbacks.c
 *
 *  Created on: 13 May 2020
 *      Author: Paul
 */
#include <circbuf.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "myfuncs.h"
#include "myirqcallbacks.h"
#include "globals.h"

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)  // Outgoing debug, control and up-the-line data.
{
    if( huart->Instance == huart1.Instance)
    {
        if( buf_tx1.count > 0)

        {
            uint8_t item;
            cb_pop_front(&buf_tx1, &item );
            if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, &item, 1 )!= HAL_OK)
                    Error_Handler();
        }
    }
    __NOP();// Check all data sent
}
//HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)

void HAL_GPIO_EXT1_Callback ( uint16_t GPIO_Pin)  //Reset UICC detected
{
    if( GPIO_Pin == SIM_RST_Pin)
    {
        HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(GPIO_Pin);
          SIMState= SIM_STATE_ATR;
          SIM_ATR_Processing = 1;
          SIM_ATR_BytesExpected = 2; //  +last byte will always be TK (CheckByte)
          SIM_ATR_COUNT = 0;
          debug("\nSIM-Reset!  Proc. ATR\n");
    }
}



void    HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)  // Data from SIM
    {
        if( huart->Instance == huart2.Instance)
        {
            uint8_t item;
            if(HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &item, 1)!=HAL_OK)
                Error_Handler();
            //cb_push_back(&buf_rx2, &item);   // Still need to send this up the line, just using local copy to set speed and to debug
            if(SIM_ATR_Processing)
                processATRByte(item);
        }
    __NOP();// Check all data received
    }
```

I'm thinking this is more about my flaky c file structure knowledge than anything else but I've been on it for a couple of days now and any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Someone did spot the error in the function names for which thank you.  Sadly this didn't solve the  problem, I must have generated this one in my flapping about trying to solve the main problem.
What fixed it in the end was regenerating code the MX configurator, which rebuilds the stm32F1xx_hal_gpio.c/h and stm32F1xx_hal_gpio.ex.c/h files.  I deleted the local copies first.